# addEventListener not working as intended in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, addeventlistener

My slider starts from the startValue then goes to displayValue and then goes to end value i.e 100% to 0% to -100% left. Once the transition to left is complete, I want the slide to become invisible, then go to start position and become visible again so it can again go through all of the cycle. However, my add event listener not working properly. I have  market the relevant portion of the code.

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajaybirbal/zy0pq7uc/15/

I have variables that I have initialized before for my slider that I have explained below.

```
animationType = "left"
startValue = "-100%"
displayValue = "0%"
endValue = "-100%"
currentSlide is a int that measures what current slide is to be shown.
```

My part of the code that starts my slider is here and I have explained variables in commont: -

```
/**
 * Initializes all slides to start position except the first slide for first time running
 * or running after the slider is reset.
 */
function setSlidesPosition(startPos = 1, maxPos = numberOfSlides){
    for ( let index = startPos; index < maxPos; index++){
        slides[index].style[animationType] = startValue;
    }
}

/***
 * Starts the slideshow.
 */
function startSlideshow(){

    setSlidesPosition();

    setInterval(() => {

        //Is the slideshow loaded for the first time
        //was there a reset done? //true or false
        if (firstTimeLoaded){
            currentSlide = 0;
            firstTimeLoaded = false;
        }

        //Display the current slide
        //numberOfSlides is total number of slides in slideshow
        if (currentSlide === (numberOfSlides - 1)){     //If it is the last slide
            slides[0].style[animationType] = displayValue;
        } else {
            slides[currentSlide + 1].style[animationType] = displayValue;
        }

        //Make slide that just displayed go to the end position
        slides[currentSlide].style[animationType] = endValue;

        //--------------Issue here------------------------
        //I want slide to go to starting position as soon as transition to end location is complete
        slides[currentSlide].addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
            slides[currentSlide].style.visibility = "none";
            slides[currentSlide].style[animationType] = startValue;
            slides[currentSlide].addEventListener('transitionend', () =>  {
                slides[currentSlide].style.visibility = "visible";
            })
        })

        //reset the counter if last slide is reached else increase the counter
        if (currentSlide === (numberOfSlides - 1)){
            currentSlide = 0;
            setSlidesPosition();
        } else {
            currentSlide++;
        }

    }, duration);
}
```

Why isn't my add event listener being called properly? My slides go invisible midway.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: *I have three variables for my slider that I have explained below* - shows 4 variable ... not sure the others are self explanatory in that case

Comment: Don't  add eventlisteners more than once! You add every interval AND again in the transitionend

Comment: @mplungjan Still not working!

Comment: "still not working" is not useful

Comment: I have  shared my jsfiddle code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajaybirbal/zy0pq7uc/15/  @mplungjan

Comment: Why do I have to go there.  Also that link can become stale. Only reason to use JSFiddle over Stacksnippets is the different copyright model. Is that not the reason, please post here

Comment: I do not understand your issue, but to delegate, you can do this OUTSIDE the interval assuming currentSlide is a global var: `document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      slides[currentSlide].style.visibility = "none";
      slides[currentSlide].style[animationType] = startValue;
      slides[currentSlide].style.visibility = "visible";
    })`